# how can I make bash block on getting a line of stdout from a job that I have spawned

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, ipc

I need to launch a process within a shell script. (It is a special logging process.) It needs to live for most of the shell script, while some other processes will run, and then at the end we will kill it.

A problem that I am having is that I need to launch this process, and wait for it to "warm up", before proceeding to launch more processes.

I know that I can wait for a line of input from a pipe using `read`, and I know that I can spawn a child process using `&`. But when I use them together, it doesn't work like I expect.

---

As a mockup:

When I run this (sequential):

```
(sleep 1 && echo "foo") > read
```

my whole shell blocks for 1 second, and the echo of `foo` is consumed by read, as I expect.

I want to do something very similar, except that I run the `"foo"` job in parallel:

```
(sleep 1 && echo "foo" &) > read
```

But when I run this, my shell doesn't block at all, it returns instantly -- I don't know why the read doesn't wait for a line to be printed on the pipe?

Is there some easy way to combine "spawning of a job" (`&`) with capturing the stdout pipe *within the original shell*?

---

An example that is very close to what I actually need is, I need to rephrase this somehow,

```
(sleep 1 && echo "foo" && sleep 20 &) > read; echo "bar"
```

and I need for it to print `"bar"` after exactly one second, and not immediately, or 21 seconds later.

Comment: Check if [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash) is useful for you.

Comment: I think it probably is useful, thanks! I mean, in his examples the reader is blocking on a pipe that hasn't been written to yet... I didn't realize that named pipe has a different semantics (is that what's going on here?) Is the problem that there's no actual pipe in my examples or something? I wonder, is named pipe necessary for this effect? I wish I knew more about shell

Comment: @LuisMuñoz your link completely solved my problem, thank you! would accept as the answer

Comment: Glad to hear. Post he answer yourself as I didn't write any code :) . If you still want to show your appreciation, click the up arrow left to the first comment (this comment adds something useful...).

Comment: `some-command > read` is the redirection syntax which would create a file named `read`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using named pipes, pretty close to what I used in the end. Thanks to Luis for his comments suggesting named pipes.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set up temporary fifo
FIFO=/tmp/test_fifo
rm -f "$FIFO"
mkfifo "$FIFO"

# Spawn a second job that writes to FIFO after some time
sleep 1 && echo "foo" && sleep 20 >$FIFO &

# Block the main job on getting a line from the FIFO
read line <$FIFO

# So that we can see when the main job exits
echo $line
```

Thanks also to commenter Emily E., the example that I posted that was misbehaving was indeed writing to a file called `read` instead of using the shell-builtin command `read`.